# How to scan a file for a specific letter in Java

Tags: java

I need to take a file that a user chooses and scan that file for a letter that a user chooses, and then output how many times the user's letter appeared in the file.

I know how to get the user input and get the user to select a file, as well as scanning the file, but I cannot figure out a way to check each character within a file for a specific letter. The closest I have been able to come is this:

```
public class FileLetterCounter
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    int count = 0, stringLength;
    String file, a = "a";
    Scanner fileScanner, letterScan;
    ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();

    fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("lab6.txt"));

    while (fileScanner.hasNext())
    {
      line.add(fileScanner.next());
  
      for (int index = 0; index < line.length(); index ++)
      {
        if (line.get(index).contains(a));
        {
          count++;
        }
      }
    } 
  }  
}
```

This doesn't work because the length() method does not work on an ArrayList, and I am unsure of how to approach the problem. I am asking this question because I found a similar one, but the recommended solution was to use what I have right now in my for loop (line.length()), but this won't work.

Comment: `length()` doesn't work on collections but `size()` certainly does.   Also your `for` loop should be _outside_ of your while loop because you want to accumulate the lines and then count them.  Alternatively would be to not have the list at all but just count each line when you read it in.   I would also use a `BufferedReader` and `readLine()` instead of the scanner.  To figure out what's going wrong I would try some printf debugging. 
 Or in Java `System.out.println()` debugging.  https://tedspence.com/the-art-of-printf-debugging-7d5274d6af44

Comment: @Gray I have to use the scanner based on my assignment. Will size() work similarly to length()?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding it to the list, just scan the text into a string, iterate each character of the string to check if the character matches with the search character, and increase the value of `count` for each match.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int count = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the char to search: ");
        char searchChar = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("lab6.txt"));

        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            String text = fileScanner.next();
            for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
                if (text.charAt(index) == searchChar) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The character " + searchChar + " appears " + count + " times in the file.");
        fileScanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `fileScanner` should be closed to release a file pointer!

Comment: I would prefer `try with resources`.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik - Thanks for the feedback. I would also do with try-with-resources but given the maturity of the OP, I did not introduce it in my answer; rather, I kept the focus on how to get the count which was the main problem the OP has asked a solution for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to search a character in the whole file. Modified the code by removing all those unnecessary variables. Also I don't see any use of adding each line to a list of strings.

Idea is to scan through each line and increment count if the current character character matches your character

```
public class FileLetterCounter
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    int count = 0;
    char targetLetter = 'a'; //define whatever you want or take it from user input
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("lab6.txt"));
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
      String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
      for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
        if(line.charAt(i) == targetLetter) {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this implementation with `Streams`. Looks pretty nice to me. Additionally **do not forget to provide `Charset`**, otherwise you could get unexpected results.

```
public static long countCharacterInFile(Path file, char ch, Charset charset) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file, charset)) {
        return stream.map(String::codePoints)
                     .flatMap(IntStream::boxed)
                     .filter(c -> c == ch)
                     .count();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Path file = Paths.get("lab6.txt");
System.out.println(countCharacterInFile(file, 'e', StandardCharsets.UTF_8));    // 666
```